# Zip list with arrays to a dict doesn't produce correct results

Tags: python, dictionary, sympy

I have this code:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np

arr = [np.array([ 1, 2,  3, 4]), np.array([ 5, 6, 7, 8])]
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')
var = [a,b]

new_dict = dict(zip(str(var), arr))
```

And my output is:

```
print(new_dict)

{'[': array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'a': array([5, 6, 7, 8])}
```

instead of:

```
{'a': array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'b': array([5, 6, 7, 8])}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a list to `str()`, it gives you the representation of that list as a string, which includes brackets and commas. You want the string representation of each value in that list:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(map(str, var), arr))
```

Or, better yet, since `var` seems to hold strings anyway:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(var, arr))
```